# “Error: The given sign-in provider is disabled for Firebase project.” but I enabled Firebase Google auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

"Error: The given sign-in provider is disabled for Firebase project."  I enabled it in Firebase console under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section:

[image: enabled it in the Firebase console]

Comment: 1. Which sign in method exactly do you thin you enabled? Please provide more information about your problem and what your expected behavior is. 2. The image you provided should maybe show an screenshot of your console with the sign in method you think you enabled.

Comment: That see a to be user name and password, what Google has to do with it? Is the mail use gmail? There is no relation there, email and password is another auth method